# Component doesn't load when using mdbootstrap carousel with angular universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, mdbootstrap

I have used mdbootstrap carousel with angular universal. The rest components are working fine but i am getting an issue using carousel on homescreen. The homepage doesnt loads, but when i access different page and call the homepage again the page gets loaded.

**My homepage componenet HTML file.**

```
<section style="background-color: #00bfff">
  <div class="home">
    <mdb-carousel [isControls]="false" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" [animation]="'fade'">
      <mdb-slide>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="home-slider">
            <div></div>
            <div class="home-head">
              <p class="home-head-1">Get your personal career coach</p>
              <br>
              <button class="home-button">KNOW MORE</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img class="img-fluid home-img mx-auto d-block" src="/assets/images/slider/1.png" alt="boardinfinity" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mdb-slide>
      <mdb-slide>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="home-slider">
            <div></div>
            <div class="home-head">
              <p class="home-head-1">Get a career boost with great jobs.</p>
              <br>
              <button class="home-button">KNOW MORE</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img class="img-fluid home-img mx-auto d-block" src="/assets/images/slider/2.png" alt="boardinfinity" style="position: relative;top: 3px;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mdb-slide>
    </mdb-carousel>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: any error in the console ( server/client side)?

Comment: @David No error on console

Comment: what do you see on the home page then if it does not load?

Comment: @David Infinite loading with waiting for localhost and i get this on my node console GET / - - ms - -

Comment: Did you see t hat thread? Not sure if it's the same problem https://mdbootstrap.com/support/carousel-is-not-working-with-angular-universal/

Comment: @David It is working now but now i cannot set interval more than 0, can you help me out with that

Comment: Sorry, I don't know mdboostrap

Comment: What's your probalem now exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add `[interval]="0"` to your `<mdb-carousel>` element. This should work for you.